# In p5.js clear elements in draw() that change every frame, but leave expensive element (a map) created in setup()

Tags: d3.js, processing, p5.js

Using p5.js and d3.js for mapping, I loaded a US map of specific counties in `setup()` on a canvas. This takes around 1/2 - 1 second to load because the shapefile is fairly large

In `draw()`, I'm creating some text, ellipses, etc that I want to update using sliders, and will probably create some additional animation.

Typically in p5.js, you can just use `background(255)` right after `draw()` to wipe all out, and make the transitions smooth so nothing overlaps, old ellipses and text are wiped clean, etc.

**The problem I'm having is my initial map is so expensive to load, I can't wipe it out and redraw it every frame, it lags behind all. I need to draw the map once, and then essentially do a background(255) on all other elements except the map, or basically clear out all that's created in draw() every frame while leaving the map I created in setup() on the canvas. Or just clear all elements except the map.**

Below is hypothetical code I made in a p5 editor. The rect in the background is a placeholder for the map. You can see that because text and the ellipses aren't wiped out, they overlap, and once the ellipses reach a certain size you cannot decrease their size because the large ones remain.

https://editor.p5js.org/dfeusse/sketches/HkJe2Kj9m

Below is an example using `background()` which makes the p5.js code ideal and clean, but the rect (ie the map) created in setup is obviously wiped out and disappears.

https://editor.p5js.org/dfeusse/sketches/HJWtr5oqQ

Is there a way to keep one element on the canvas while drawing over all other elements, like conceptually using background, or clearing, or some other method I obviously don't really know about? Thanks for any thoughts and help!

Below is a screenshot where you can see the map I'm drawing, basically the same as the placeholder rect, and trying to alter the ellipses with sliders.
[image]

Comment: How do you do the drawing of this background? If you load it into an `image` variable in `setup`, perhaps it will display quicker in `draw`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options:

- If the map is always the same, then you can save it to an image file. Load it into a variable in the `setup()` function, and then draw it in the `draw()` function.
- If the map might change between runs of your program, then you can draw the map to a buffer in `setup()` and then draw that buffer in `draw()`. The `createGraphics()` function will come in handy here.

Here's a simplified example:

```
    var pg;

    function setup() {
      createCanvas(100, 100);
      pg = createGraphics(100, 100);
      pg.background(100);
      pg.noStroke();
      pg.ellipse(pg.width / 2, pg.height / 2, 50, 50);
    }

    function draw() {
      background(200);
      image(pg, 50, 50);
      image(pg, 0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
```

Comment: if the background image is the same size as the canvas there is no need to clear the background in the `draw()`, then just `image(pg, 0, 0);` is enough

Comment: @rioV8 That's going to depend on context. For example if the background image contains transparency, then you still might want to clear out old frames. Also note that you can pass an image directly into the `background()` function. But again, this all depends on context. My answer is meant as a general example, not a catch-all for every situation.

Comment: you clear the pg background with a solid color so no transparencies

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, in this particular example. But it depends entirely on context.

Comment: @KevinWorkman and riov8 Thanks so much for the answers and help! I think either option will work. Just to add context in 2 seconds, I basically used this example http://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/f46df2272b289a9ce4e7 as a starting point and loaded the map using d3.json() in setup(). The map will be static. I tried to google buffers and saw this link among others https://p5js.org/examples/structure-create-graphics.html. Kevin, I'm sorry I'm a self taught guy, not a mecca of CS knowledge, do you have a go to resource that explains offscreen buffers? Trying to think of the tradeoffs of your two recs.

Comment: @DanielF I'm pretty sure rioV8 and I are talking about the same solution. He's just saying that you might not need to call the `background()` function if your buffer will cover up the whole screen. As for resources, the best place to start is always [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics).

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thanks for all the help! Sorry for another question, but Im tripping up connecting the buffer with my map, the step between "pg = createGraphics(500, 250)" and "image(pg,x,y)". In p5's docs, a shapes assigned by pg.SHAPE ie pg.ellipse. A map though isnt a predefined p5 shape. Below is the short code I'm trying to assign to the buffer. 

d3.json('us.json', function(error, us) {
     d3.json('counties.json', function(error, counties) {
     }
}

I can't do something like "pg.d3.json(etc etc)" though.


Is there documentation you've seen putting non-p5 shapes in a buffer?

Comment: @DanielF I'm not really familiar with the D3 library, but it looks like it's drawing to the canvas directly? In that case, you could maybe try to use two separate but overlapping canvas elements?

Comment: @KevinWorkman the us.json mapfile is too big for the p5 web editor to handle so it's not rendering unfortunately, here is the code in setup(): https://editor.p5js.org/dfeusse/sketches/rk6qWQh57. But drew the d3 map onto the canvas with the code:
        var myCanvas = createCanvas(width, height);
        // give canvas an id to reference
        myCanvas.id('defaultCanvas');
        var canvas = document.getElementById('defaultCanvas');
Then keyed off of canvas. Tried to sub buffer with canvas, but didn't work. Any ideas? I'm not too sure what you meant by making two canvas'.

Comment: Before this whole thread, I had the idea of just drawing d3 onto svg like usual, and then drawing p5 onto the canvas, and just overlapping the two using the same projection and scale, but it seems like you can't overlap an svg and canvas block unless I was doing something wrong.